# $K$ is a tempered distribution ,and $m=K \hat{}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function away from the origin . Show that $K$ is regular .

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

> **Definition $1$:** A distribution $K$ is regular if and only if $K$ agree with a $C^{\infty}$ function away from the origin .
>
> **Definition 2** : $K \hat{}$ denote the fourier transform of the distribution $K$
>
> **$C^{(n)}$-normalized bump function** : Function $\varphi \in C^{\infty}$ supported in the unit ball and $\sup_x |\partial_x^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|\le1$ for all $|\alpha|\le n$ .
>
> **Cancelation property :** For some fixed $n\ge1$ , there is an $A$ so that $\sup_{0 \lt r} |K(\varphi(rx)|\le A$ for all $C^{(n)}$-normalized bump function $\varphi$ .

**Theorem :** If $K$ is a tempered distribution , and $m=K \hat{}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function away from the origin that satisfied $|\partial_x^{\alpha}
m(x)|\le c_{\alpha} |x|^{-\alpha}$ . Then $K$ is also a regular distribution .

In Stein's functional analysis Page$_{135}$ , it said the following three definition of Calderon-Zygmund distributions are equivalent .
$(1)$ $K$ is regular and satisfies the differential inequalities $|\partial_x^{\alpha} k(x)|\le c_{\alpha}|x|^{-d-|\alpha|}$ for all $\alpha$ together with the cencelation property .
$(2)$ $K$ is tempered , and $m=K \hat{}$ is a function that is $C^{\infty}$ away from the origin that satisfies $|\partial_x^{\alpha}m(x)|\le c_{\alpha}'|x|^{-|\alpha|}$ for all $\alpha$ .
$(3)$ $K$ is a regular distribution that satisfies the differential inequalities $|\partial_x^{\alpha} k(x)|\le c_{\alpha}|x|^{-d-|\alpha|}$ and $K \hat{}$ is a bound function .

If the word "tempered" in $(2)$ was replaced by "regular" , then I can show three definition above are equivalent . However , in stein's proof ,it seems that he forget to prove this .

**My attempt :** First consider the case when $m$ has compact support . In this case , we can let $$k(x)=\int m(x) e^{2\pi i nx}\,dx$$ Note that both $\varphi \hat{}$ and $m$ are in $L^1$ , then we have $$K(\varphi \hat{})=K \hat{}(\varphi)=\int m(x)\varphi(x) \,dx=\int k(x)\varphi \hat{} (x) \,dx$$ For all $\varphi \in S(R^d)$ , and suppored outside origin . Then we find $K_0(\varphi)=\int k(x)\varphi(x)$ is regular and $K-K_0$ is supported at origin . Since $|\partial_x^{\alpha}m(x)|\le c_{\alpha}'|x|^{-|\alpha|}$ for all $\alpha$ , we have $K_0=K$ . However , when $m$ is not compact , $\int m(x) e^{2\pi i nx}$ might make no sense . For example , $K=\delta $ , then $m=1$ satisfied condition $(2)$ but $\int e^{2\pi inx}$ diverges while $\delta$ agrees with function $0$ .

Comment: @ reuns If $K=pv(\frac1x)$ , then $K$ agrees with $\frac 1x$ outside origin . Assume we can find such $T$ , then we have $K=f+\sum_1^N \partial^{\alpha}_x \delta$ . So we must have $f(x)=\frac 1x$ whenever $x\neq 0$ , and $f$ is not smooth .

Comment: Right then $K$ is regular iff $x^a K$ is tempered smooth for some $a$ iff $\varphi x^a K$ is Schwartz iff $\hat{\varphi} \ast \partial^a \hat{K}$ is Schwartz for any  $\hat{\varphi}  $ Schwartz

Comment: @ reuns I did not see why we have $\varphi * x^a K \in S$ , since $x^a K$ might not compact . Indeed , let $K=pv(\frac 1x)$ and $a=1$ , then we have $\varphi * x^a K=\int \varphi(x-y)\,dy=c$ which is not in $S$ when $c \neq 0$ .

Comment: One idea: 
Take $\rho \in C_c^\infty$ such that $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of origin. Then $\rho K\hat{}$ has compact support and you can treat it as you want. And for $|\alpha|$ big enough $\partial^\alpha \left( (1-\rho) K\hat{} \right) \in L^1$ so that $\int \partial^\alpha \left( (1-\rho) K\hat{} \right)(\xi) \, e^{i\xi x} \, d\xi$ is defined.

Comment: @ md2perpe I find that even the word "tempered" was replaced by "tempered and regular" , the proposition above is still not valid .  
Let $K=-4\pi^2 |x|^2 $  , then we have $K\hat{}=\Delta \delta$  which agrees with $0$ away from the origin and satisfies $|\partial_x^{\alpha}
0|\le c_{\alpha} |x|^{-\alpha}$ . However , with simple observation , we see we can not have $|\partial_x^{\alpha} k(x)|\le c_{\alpha}|x|^{-d-|\alpha|}$ .